# docker-compose: is the depends_on meaningless? No individual exit dependency, no individual restart dependency?

Tags: docker-compose

To my surprise, even in the latest docker-compose, the `depends_on` settings still can not do following things:

suppose I've defined that A depends on B,

- if B exit, then A exit.   (I don't want use the `--abort-on-container-exit` which stop all on any exit)
- restarting A will automatically restart B

Are these features not available in docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) states:

> #### depends_on
>
> Express dependency between services. Service dependencies cause the following behaviors:
>
> - `docker-compose up` starts services in dependency order.
> - `docker-compose up SERVICE` automatically includes SERVICE’s dependencies.
> - `docker-compose stop` stops services in dependency order.

Thus, `depends_on` control startup and shutdown ***order*** when you use `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose stop`, nothing else. It won't stop a container if it's dependency exited and neither it will wait for a dependency to become ready for incoming connections.

I recommend you this great short article: [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/). It brings some light on why it is as it is.

Comment: thank you. I am familiar with this order control, just curious, it has been so long since first docker-compose come up, the depends_on specification is still so ridiculous, you can not trust the start order because it does not mean the service init code started.